# How to set length of Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_FLOAT in magento 2 custom module setup script?

Tags: magento2

I want to set length of

> TYPE::FLOAT

in my custom module installation script by using the following code.

```
$installer->getConnection()
      ->newTable($tableName)
      ->addColumn(
          'boxlength', 
          Table::TYPE_FLOAT, 
          array(), 
          array(
                'nullable'  => false,
          ), 
          'boxlength')
```

I want to set length (10,4) to insert values like 10.5555.

 But right now it is not accepting 10.5555 due to set length as (10,0).

Help needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use '**decimal**' instead of '**float**' for storing data value

Float - 7 digits (32 bit)

Double-15-16 digits (64 bit)

Decimal -28-29 significant digits (128 bit)

```
try {

    $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('table_name'),
        'test',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
            'length' => '10,4',
            'comment' => 'Test Data Column'
        ]
    );

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $installer->getConnection()->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```